# Add a close button - Bootstrap 3 Slide in Menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know if it's possible to add a close button in the sidebar just above the search bar.

I try a lot of thing but it's doesn't work

Example : we can see a close button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozE3f.png)

Here my code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {


    //stick in the fixed 100% height behind the navbar but don't wrap it
    $('#slide-nav.navbar-inverse').after($('<div class="inverse" id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));
  
    $('#slide-nav.navbar-default').after($('<div id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));  

    // Enter your ids or classes
    var toggler = '.navbar-toggle';
    var pagewrapper = '.columns-container';
    var navigationwrapper = '.navbar-header';
    var menuwidth = '100%'; // the menu inside the slide menu itself
    var slidewidth = '80%';
    var menuneg = '-100%';
    var slideneg = '-80%';


    $("#slide-nav").on("click", toggler, function (e) {

        var selected = $(this).hasClass('slide-active');

        $('#slidemenu').stop().animate({
            left: selected ? menuneg : '0px'
        });

        $('#navbar-height-col').stop().animate({
            left: selected ? slideneg : '0px'
        });

        $(pagewrapper).stop().animate({
            left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });

        $(navigationwrapper).stop().animate({
            left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });


        $(this).toggleClass('slide-active', !selected);
        $('#slidemenu').toggleClass('slide-active');


        $('.columns-container, .navbar, body, .navbar-header').toggleClass('slide-active');


    });


    var selected = '#slidemenu, .columns-container, body, .navbar, .navbar-header';


    $(window).on("resize", function () {

        if ($(window).width() > 767 && $('.navbar-toggle').is(':hidden')) {
            $(selected).removeClass('slide-active');
        }


    });




});
```

```css
/* adjust body when menu is open */
body.slide-active {
    overflow-x: hidden
}
/*first child of #page-content so it doesn't shift around*/
.no-margin-top {
    margin-top: 0px!important
}
/*wrap the entire page content but not nav inside this div if not a fixed top, don't add any top padding */
#page-content {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 70px;
    left: 0;
}
#page-content.slide-active {
    padding-top: 0
}



/* put toggle bars on the left :: not using button */
#slide-nav .navbar-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 0;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
/* icon bar prettyup - optional */
#slide-nav .navbar-toggle > .icon-bar {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#slide-nav .navbar-toggle.slide-active .icon-bar {
    background: orange
}
.navbar-header {
    position: relative
}
/* un fix the navbar when active so that all the menu items are accessible */
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
    position: relative
}
/* screw writing importants and shit, just stick it in max width since these classes are not shared between sizes */
@media (max-width:767px) { 
 #slide-nav .container {
     margin: 0!important;
     padding: 0!important;
      height:100%;
 }
 #slide-nav .navbar-header {
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0 15px;
 }
 #slide-nav .navbar.slide-active {
     position: absolute;
     width: 80%;
     top: -1px;
     z-index: 1000;
 }
 #slide-nav #slidemenu {
     background: #f7f7f7;
     left: -100%;
     width: 80%;
     min-width: 0;
     position: absolute;
     padding-left: 0;
     z-index: 2;
     top: -8px;
     margin: 0;
 }
 #slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav {
     min-width: 0;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
 }
 #slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li a {
     min-width: 0;
     width: 80%;
     white-space: normal;
 }
 #slide-nav {
     border-top: 0
 }
 #slide-nav.navbar-inverse #slidemenu {
     background: #333
 }
 /* this is behind the navigation but the navigation is not inside it so that the navigation is accessible and scrolls*/
 #navbar-height-col {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     height: 100%;
      bottom:0;
     width: 80%;
     left: -80%;
     background: #f7f7f7;
 }
 #navbar-height-col.inverse {
     background: #333;
     z-index: 1;
     border: 0;
 }
 #slide-nav .navbar-form {
     width: 100%;
     margin: 8px 0;
     text-align: center;
     overflow: hidden;
     /*fast clearfixer*/
 }
 #slide-nav .navbar-form .form-control {
     text-align: center
 }
 #slide-nav .navbar-form .btn {
     width: 100%
 }
}
@media (min-width:768px) { 
 #page-content {
     left: 0!important
 }
 .navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
     position: fixed
 }
 .navbar-header {
     left: 0!important
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <meta charset=utf-8 />
 <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="slide-nav">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-toggle"> 
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
   </div>
   <div id="slidemenu">
     
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="search" placeholder="search" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          </form>
     
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link test long title goes here</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
          
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  
  <!--wrap the page content do not style this-->
 <div id="page-content">
   
  <div class="container" >
    <h1 class="no-margin-top">Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
    
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>

    
    
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>

    
    
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>

    
    
    
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>

    
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>

    
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>

    
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>

    
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>

    
    
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>

    
    
   </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
  
 </div>
 <!-- /#page-content -->

</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: Woah, that's a lot of code. Do you have a more specific question than just "can someone finish my project?"

Comment: yes, it's possible to do so, with help of jquery

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>nav with close button</title>
  <style>
    #close{
      display:none;
      float:right;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      background:#ccc;
      padding: 8px;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       
       $( ".man" ).one("click", function() {
        $(".man").hide();
         $("#close").show();
         
});
       
       $( ".man" ).click(function() {
        $("#navbar .nav").show();
         $("#close").show();
         
}); 
       
       $( "#close" ).click(function() { 
          $("#navbar .nav").hide();
           $(".man").show();
            $("#close").hide();
});
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Static navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            
         <a href="#"><span class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id='close'>x</span></a> <!--Close button-->
            
            <button type="button" class="man navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">              
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what you wanted, added a close button and used jquery to close nav menu, to help in for a mobile device, Happy Coding!